# GoogleApiClient Invalid Account

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm playing around with an Android watch. I call GoogleApiClient.connect() but it complains about the invalid account. Here is the related code:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
mClient.connect();
```

I use similar code in Nexus 5 and it works. But the watch doesn't like it. The error code is INVALID_ACCOUNT.

**UPDATE**

It is paired with a phone which has google play services and a valid google account. I tried similar code in the phone and it worked.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried other people's code and applications. These couldn't connect either. I reset the device but the problem is still there. Any idea?

Comment: If you don't already have it, add some logs to the callback methods. You should be able to get more information about what goes wrong. Post the logcat output here if you still need help.